# How to save item into list only once?

Tags: list, javascript, jquery

I am trying save the below into list in SharePoint, but each item is getting saved twice. I need to save only once. What's wrong?

```
function sumcalval() {

    alert("save function called");

    var pageload1 = 0;

    var rowCount1 = $("#data_table_1 tbody tr").length;
    alert("rowCount1 "+rowCount1);
    var rowcountgrid1 = rowCount1;
    alert("rowcountgrid1 " + rowcountgrid1);

    for (var j = 0; j < rowCount1; j++) {


        gridval1 = $("#row" + j).find(".projectcode").val();
        alert("gridval1 " + gridval1);
        gridval2 = $("#row" + j).find(".projectname").val();
        alert("gridval2" + gridval2);

        gridval3 = $("#row" + j).find(".atlaspartno").val();
        alert("gridval3" + gridval3);
        gridval4 = $("#row" + j).find(".atlasdescription").val();
        alert("gridval4" + gridval4);
        gridval5 = $("#row" + j).find(".stdnstd").val();
        alert("gridval5" + gridval5);
        gridval6 = $("#row" + j).find(".mfgpur").val();
        alert("gridval6" + gridval6);
        gridval7 = $("#row" + j).find(".finalqty").val();

        gridval8 = $("#row" + j).find(".uom").val();

        gridval9 = $("#row" + j).find(".qtyatquotequotedcogs").val();
        alert("gridval9" + gridval9);
        gridval10 = $("#row" + j).find(".unitratequotedcogs").val();

        gridval11 = $("#row" + j).find(".totalquotedcogs").val();

        gridval12 = $("#row" + j).find(".targetunitcost").val();

        gridval13 = $("#row" + j).find(".targetcosttotal").val();

        gridval14 = $("#row" + j).find(".rswp").val();


        gridval17 = $("#row" + j).find(".unitratepocosttracking").val();

        gridval18 = $("#row" + j).find(".pocosttotaltracking").val();

        gridval19 = $("#row" + j).find(".rswptracking").val();

        gridval20 = $("#row" + j).find(".unitraterevenue").val();

        gridval21 = $("#row" + j).find(".totalrevenue").val();

        //  TotalRevenue = TotalRevenue + gridvalue21;

        var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);//Get the SharePoint Context object based upon the URL  
        var appCtxSite = new SP.AppContextSite(ctx, hostweburl);
        var web = appCtxSite.get_web(); //Get the Site  



        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("wbslist"); //Get the List based upon the Title  
        var listCreationInformation = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation(); //Object for creating Item in the List  
        var oListItem11 = list.addItem(listCreationInformation);

        oListItem11.set_item('wbscode', QueryStringValue);
        oListItem11.set_item('projectcode', listItemInfo1);
        oListItem11.set_item('projectname', listItemInfo2);

        oListItem11.set_item('WBSTaskno', gridvalue1);
        //oListItem1.set_item('TaskCategory', gridvaluecat);

        oListItem11.set_item('TaskName', gridval2);
        oListItem11.set_item('atlaspartno', gridval3);
        oListItem11.set_item('atlasdescription', gridval4);
        oListItem11.set_item('stdnstd', gridval5);
        oListItem11.set_item('mfgpur', gridval6);
        oListItem11.set_item('finalqty', gridval7);
        oListItem11.set_item('uom', gridval8);
        oListItem11.set_item('qtyatquotequotedcogs', gridval9);
        oListItem11.set_item('unitratequotedcogs', gridval10);
        oListItem11.set_item('totalquotedcogs', gridval11);
        oListItem11.set_item('targetunitcost', gridval12);
        oListItem11.set_item('targetcosttotal', gridval13);
        oListItem11.set_item('rswp', gridval14);
        //oListItem1.set_item('ponoitemwisefilledbypro', gridvalue15);
        oListItem11.set_item('unitratepocosttracking', gridval17);
        oListItem11.set_item('pocosttotaltracking', gridval18);
        oListItem11.set_item('rswptracking', gridval19);
        oListItem11.set_item('unitraterevenue', gridval20);
        oListItem11.set_item('totalrevenue', gridval21);
        oListItem11.update(); //Update the List Item  

        ctx.load(oListItem11);

        ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            pageload++;

            if (pageload == rowcountgrid) {

                alert("Saving Completed");

            }
        }, 1);

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please write below mention code outside the For-loop & try it.

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
var appCtxSite = new SP.AppContextSite(ctx, hostweburl);
var web = appCtxSite.get_web(); //Get the Site  

var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("wbslist");
var listCreationInformation = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();  
var oListItem11 = list.addItem(listCreationInformation);
```

Comment: Items are not saving...

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing with this so your listItem inside the methode is always the same:

```
function createListItem() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My New Item!');
    oListItem.set_item('Body', 'Hello World!');

    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185011(v=office.14).aspx